# Word usages for hearsay: ～そうです vs ～って

Tags: word-choice

For hearsay (伝聞), one can append そうです to the plain form of an adjective and verb. For example:

> 体にいいそうです - Heard it's good for the body

There is also another way to say that and that's using って. For example:

> 体にいいって - Heard it's good for the body

The question is, what is the difference between these 2 sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～って。」 is quite casual and colloquial.

いい**そうです**。 -- polite and formal
いい**そうだ**。 -- less polite
いいんだ**って**。or いい**って**。 -- informal, casual, and colloquial

eg

> ごま油は、体にいい**そうです**よ。-- You might say this to your boss, teacher, or customer.
>   ごま油って、体にいいんだ**って**。-- You might say this to your family or friends.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to say..... いいって instead of..... んだって?

Comment: Yeah, it's correct. 「ごま油って、体にいいって。」is okay, but 「体にいいんだって。」 might sound more natural in your case cos んだって sounds like giving new, more important info, while 「体にいいって。」 sounds like simply reporting someone else's comment.  Some other examples: 「店に電話したら、まだ在庫あるって。」「お父さんに聞いたけど、知らないって。」

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Chocolate's answer, it may be worth noting the actual literal difference between the two forms:

「そうです」 means, basically, "it appears to be that way", so 「体にいいそうです」 literally means "It seems that it's good for the body" (the implication being that it seems that way because people have said it's so).

「って」 is a contraction of 「と言う」(see [Tae Kim's page](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/quotation.html#part4)), that is, it literally means "(someone) says", so 「体にいいって」 literally translates to "people say it's good for the body" (although depending on context, it might also mean "he/she says it's good for the body", etc, so one needs to be a bit more careful).

Comment: I would just point out that your literal translation of 「体にいいそうです」is the common structural translation of 「体に良さそうです」 so I think thinking about it literally runs the risk of being a bit confusing for those struggling with the two main そうです constructions ('hearsay' and 'inference').